# Running multiple versions of Silverstripe objects

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

We are working on a Silverstripe project which requires multiple versions of the same dataobjects.

The same data structure & (roughly) the same data content will be used for A-B testing so the versions would be something like this:

- Stage / Draft
- A-B Test
- B-A Test
- Live / Production

I'm guessing the [Versioned](https://api.silverstripe.org/4/SilverStripe/Versioned/Versioned.html) class can be extended to include multiple stages.

But the behaviour we require is non-linear with A-B/B-A being alternate content rather than a linear progression.

Does anyone have an approach that would work in this situation?